# Can someone explain WITH (1)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, with-statement

I am working on upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to 2016 and I fixed the following SQL. Is this a table hint with the index? I want to understand what is happening:

```
FROM u_SAMPLE_SA WITH (1)
```

Comment: yeah, looks like an unadvertised alternative to `INDEX(1) ` meaning use the clustered index. If you try it on a heap you get error `Index ID 1 on table 't' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.`

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation @MartinSmith.